# High resolution periodic timer in Qt on Windows (also OS X, Linux)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, timer

Everything I've found so far regarding timers is that it's, at best, available at a 1ms resolution. QTimer's docs claim that's the best it can provide.

I understand that OSes like Windows are not real-time OSes, but I still want to ask this question in hopes that someone knows something that could help.

So, I'm writing an app that requires a function to be called at a fairly precise but arbitrary interval, say 60 times/sec (full range: 59-61Hz). That means I need it to be called, on average, every ~16.67ms. This part of the design can't change.

The best timing source I currently have is vsync. When I go off of that, it's pretty good. It's not ideal, because the monitor's frequency is not exactly what I need to call this function at, but it can be somewhat compensated for.

The kicker is that the level of accuracy given the range I'm after is more or less available with timers, but not the level of precision I want. I can get a 16ms timer to hit exactly 16ms ~97% of the time. I can get a 17ms timer to hit exactly 17ms ~97% of the time. But no API exists to get me 16.67?

Is what I'm looking for simply not possible?

Background: The project is called [Phoenix](http://phoenix.vg/). Essentially, it's a [libretro](http://www.libretro.com/) frontend. Libretro "cores" are game console emulators encapsulated in individual shared libraries. The API function being called at a specific rate is `retro_run()`. Each call emulates a game frame and calls callbacks for audio, video and so on. In order to emulate at a console's native framerate, we must call retro_run() at exactly (or as close to) this rate, hence the timer.

Comment: You claim that you need such a timer, but you don't tell us why. I claim that you don't need such a timer. Convince me that I'm wrong. Please expand the question with details about how you intend to use the timer. There isn't much point to a timer if you're not doing I/O, so please tell us what kind of I/O you'll be doing - it might turn out that the I/O scheme has latencies etc. that make your timer obsession irrelevant (that's the most likely answer, actually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a loop that checks `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock()` and `std::this_thread::yield()` until the right time has elapsed.  If the program needs to be responsive while this is going on, you should do it in a separate thread from the one checking the main loop.

Some example code:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield

An alternative is to use `QElapsedTimer` with a value of `PerformanceCounter`.  You will still need to check it from a loop, and probably will still want to yield within that loop.  Example code: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qelapsedtimer.html

Comment: Looping and yielding maybe a solution but quite an unreliable one.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "unreliable" in more detail?  If this doesn't work, I'd like to know why.

Comment: Well, checking the precise time in a loop and executing other actions in the loop kind of counteract each other. There is a mechanisms for compensating for the executed action time to not affect the precision of this 'timer' but it all works until the action is too slow or the thread stops. And the system timer is different - the hardware invokes your function of some new or reserved thread.

Comment: If the possible delay of a `yield` is a problem, then it would also be a problem if the scheduler made you wait right before you called your function, and you want to be running with realtime priority anyway.  So would the delay of another message arriving before it in the message loop.  The Windows timer functions don't, to my knowledge, have the resolution you want.  However, you could take out the `yield` if it causes problems and just hog the CPU.  Linux has `nanosleep`.

Comment: AlexanderVX was right, it is unreliable to yield() and check the time once you return, but I found a workaround, somewhat. In my testing, if I stick yield() in a for loop that iterates, say 100 times, then I sacrifice some precision (at best, around 1us) for accuracy. In other words, the problem I had was that using QElapsedTimer was causing some overhead, and considering that yield() was being called around 200,000 times per "loop", this overhead added up to a significant amount of time added to the effective loop period. Letting some time pass in between checks seemed to mitigate that.

Comment: Thanks for the information!  I'll remember that for future reference.  Not sure why QElapsedTimer does that; do the other clocks?  Glad you found something that works.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely unnecessary to call `retro_run` at any highly controlled time in particular, as long as the average frame rate comes out right, and as long as your audio output buffers don't underflow.

First of all, you are likely to have to measuring the real time using an audio-output-based timer. Ultimately, each `retro_run` produces a chunk of audio. The audio buffer state *with the chunk added* is your timing reference: if you run  early, the buffer will be too full, if you run late, the buffer will be too empty.

This error measure can be fed into a PI controller, whose output gives you the desired delay until the next invocation of `retro_run`. This will automatically ensure that your average rate *and* phase are correct. Any systematic latencies in getting `retro_run` active will be integrated away, etc.

Secondly, you need a way of waking yourself up at the correct moment in time. Given a target time (in terms of a performance counter, for example) to call `retro_run`, you'll need a source of events that wake your code up so that you can compare the time and `retro_run` when necessary.

The simplest way of doing this would be to reimplement `QCoreApplication::notify`. You'll have a chance to `retro_run` prior to the delivery of every event, in every event loop, in every thread. Since system events might not otherwise come often enough, you'll also want to run a timer to provide a more dependable source of events. It doesn't matter what the events are: any kind of event is good for your purpose.

I'm not familiar with threading limitations of `retro_run` - perhaps you can run it in any one thread at a time. In such case, you'd want to run it on the next available thread in a pool, perhaps with the exception of the main thread. So, effectively, the events (including timer events) are used as energetically cheap sources of giving you execution context.

If you choose to have a thread dedicated to `retro_run`, it should be a high priority thread that simply blocks on a mutex. Whenever you're ready to run `retro_run` when a well-timed event comes, you unlock the mutex, and the thread should be scheduled right away, since it'll preempt most other threads - and certainly all threads in your process.

OTOH, on a low core count system, the high priority thread is likely to preempt the main (gui) thread, so you might as well invoke `retro_run` directly from whatever thread got the well-timed event.

It might of course turn out that using events from arbitrary threads to wake up the dedicated thread introduces too much worst-case latency or too much latency spread - this will be system-specific and you may wish to collect runtime statistics, switch threading and event source strategies on the fly, and stick with the best one. The choices are:

1. `retro_run` in a dedicated thread waiting on a mutex, unlock source being any thread with a well-timed event caught via `notify`,
2. `retro_run` in a dedicated thread waiting for a timer (or any other) event; events still caught via `notify`,
3. `retro_run` in a gui thread, unlock source being the events delivered to the gui thread, still caught via `notify`,
4. any of the above, but using timer events only - note that you don't care which timer events they are, they don't need to come from your timer,
5. as in #4, but selective to your timer only.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation based on Lorehead's answer. Time for all variables are in ms.
It of course needs a way to stop running and I was also thinking about subtracting half the (running average) difference between `timeElapsed` and `interval` to make the average +-n instead of +2n, where 2n is the average overshoot.

```
// Typical interval value: 1/60s ~= 16.67ms
void Looper::beginLoop( double interval ) {

    QElapsedTimer timer;
    int counter = 1;
    int printEvery = 240;
    int yieldCounter = 0;

    double timeElapsed = 0.0;

    forever {

        if( timeElapsed > interval ) {
            timer.start();

            counter++;
            if( counter % printEvery == 0 )  {
                qDebug() << "Yield() ran" << yieldCounter << "times";
                qDebug() << "timeElapsed =" << timeElapsed << "ms | interval =" << interval << "ms";
                qDebug() << "Difference:" << timeElapsed - interval << " -- " << ( ( timeElapsed - interval ) / interval ) * 100.0 << "%";
            }

            yieldCounter = 0;

            importantBlockingFunction();

            // Reset the frame timer
            timeElapsed = ( double )timer.nsecsElapsed() / 1000.0 / 1000.0;
        }

        timer.start();

        // Running this just once means massive overhead from calling timer.start() so many times so quickly
        for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
            yieldCounter++;
            QThread::yieldCurrentThread();
        }

        timeElapsed += ( double )timer.nsecsElapsed() / 1000.0 / 1000.0;

    }
}
```